# Caffeine extraction

Tags: acid-base, food-chemistry, extraction

I'm working on a caffeine extraction experiment, using dichloromethane and instant coffee. I am testing how the amount of caffeine extracted from coffee will be affected when different concentrations of NaOH are added to the coffee. However, I am not getting any results. When the extraction is being done, no caffeine is extracted. Is this correct? What should technically happen when NaOH is added to coffee?

Comment: What, with or without NaOH, you do not get any coffeine? How do you do this extraction? And why are you doing this experiment if you don't know what the NaOH should do? Please explain!

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/can-caffeine-be-separated-from-coffee